# Javascript routes/urls to functions

Tags: javascript, routes

I'm building a Javascript/AJAX heavy web application using jQuery and I'm looking for a way to map URLs/Routes to Javascript functions. I'm using the HTML5 history API and some rewrite rules so all requests will go to one HTML file but idealy what I'd like to do is something along the lines of

```
Routes.add('/some/path/', 'func_somepath');
Routes.add('/someother/path/', 'func_someotherpath');

function func_somepath(){
    alert("You're at somepath");
}

function func_someotherpath(){
   alert("You're at someotherpath");
}
```

Then when someone visited example.com/some/path/ the function 'func_somepath' would be called, similar with /someother/path/. It would also be nice to be able to use Rails-style or regexp variables in the URLs

```
Routes.add('/items/([a-z]+)', 'func_items');

func_items(id){
    alert('You requested '+id+'!');
}
```

Does anything like this already exist or would I have to write it myself? I don't mind writing it myself but if something already exists there's no point. I'd also like to avoid using 'exec' so how would I go about calling the named functions in Routes.add?

Comment: This sounds like server-side stuff more than client-side stuff...

Comment: @samarudge, missingno is right kid.

Comment: @missingno It's for a very dynamic web-app (Think similar to how Twitter works) pulling data in from a backend JSON API (Infact, the API is the only server-side stuff, we want the frontend to be 100% HTML/JS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)'s JavaScript counter-part, [**SammyJS**](http://sammyjs.org/)? *...*ba-dum-tish**

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, not sure why I couldn't find it in Google

Answer (score 3):

Don't use eval unless you *absolutely, positively* have no other choice.

As has been mentioned, using something like this would be the best way to do it:

```
window["functionName"](arguments);
```

That, however, will not work with a namespace'd function:

```
window["My.Namespace.functionName"](arguments); // fail
```

This is how you would do that:

```
window["My"]["Namespace"]["functionName"](arguments); // succeeds
```

In order to make that easier and provide some flexibility, here is a convenience function:

```
function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
  var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
  var func = namespaces.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    context = context[namespaces[i]];
  }
  return context[func].apply(this, args);
}
```

You would call it like so:

```
executeFunctionByName("My.Namespace.functionName", window, arguments);
```

Note, you can pass in whatever context you want, so this would do the same as above:

```
executeFunctionByName("Namespace.functionName", My, arguments);
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Ember.js, senchatouch2, extjs4 are examples of a framework, that would let you do that easily